# Matching case classes without parameters list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have noticed very odd behaviour regarding case classes (not case objects) that do not have any parameters list. It appears that supertypes are completely ignored when trying to pattern-match them. I have written a small example that showcases the behavior:

```
object TestMatch {
  trait CommonType
  case class A(val x:Int) extends CommonType
  case class B extends CommonType
  case object C extends CommonType

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    printifmatched(A(1))
    printifmatched(B)
    printifmatched(C)
  }
  def printifmatched: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
    case x: CommonType => println("This is a common type", x)
    case x => println("This is not a common type", x)
  }
}
```

The output of this program is the following:

```
(This is a common type,A(1))
(This is not a common type,B)
(This is a common type,C)
```

Is this a bug? Can anyone explain why Scala is behaving this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `B` does not instantiate a `B`; it's just an object representing the type:

```
scala> B
res0: B.type = B
```

An object of class `B` is also an object of trait `CommonType`, but the type object of `B` is neither.

Adding the parentheses actually instantiates the object, so it works:

```
scala> B()
res1: B = B()

scala> printifmatched(B())
(This is a common type, B())
```

By the way, defining case classes without parentheses is deprecated:

```
scala> case class B
<console>:1: warning: case classes without a parameter list have been deprecated;
use either case objects or case classes with `()' as parameter list.
       case class B
                   ^
```

It works with the case object because objects don't need parameters because they don't need to be instantiated. `C` is a reference to the (singleton) instance of type C.

Comment: Oh dear, I see. Because the PartialFunction accepts Any, the compiler did not raise the issue. That's a very easy mistake to make... I'll avoid case classes without parameters from now on!

Answer (score 0):

regarding **SLS 5.3.2 Case Classes** companion object (what automatically generated for case classes) is not sub type of parent class of case class. 
But you call `printifmatched` with companion object.

So for call with class:

```
printifmatched(new B)
```

or call apply method of companion object what return class instance what is sub class of `CommonType`:

```
printifmatched(B.apply())
//OR:
printifmatched(B())
```